How to register service conditionally
I want to register a publisher based on a boolean value that I am handling from feature flag . I am using the publisher in one of my classes and hence it fails because the services cannot be constructed . Is it even possible to do this?
i am registering some subscribers and publishers:
if (!FeatureFlagHelper.IsEnabled(services, EnableFeatureFlag))
{
    RegisterSubscribers(services);
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
}

if (!FeatureFlagHelper.IsEnabled(services, EnableFeatureFlag))
{
    services.AddPublisher<IEmployeePublisher, EmployeePublisher>(ConfigKey);
}


Please add more context to your question to elaborate what it is you want to achieve. Ideally, post some code.

i am registering some subscribers and publishers if (!FeatureFlagHelper.IsEnabledAsync(services, EnableFeatureFlag).Result)
{
RegisterSubscribers(services);
services.AddHostedService();
}                                                                                                                if (!FeatureFlagHelper.IsEnabledAsync(services, EnableFeatureFlag).Result)
{
services.AddPublisher<IEmployeePublisher, EmployeePublisher>(ConfigKey);
}

Two possibilities - 1: make the constructor parameters for the optional types nullable, then they'll resolve as null; 2: create "null" stub implementations of the dependency and inject those when you don't want the real ones used.

You can register working publisher in case feature is enabled, but dummy publisher if not.
if(featureEnabled) {
   services.Add{Transient | Scoped | Singleton}<IPublisher, WorkingPublisher>();
} else {
   service.Add{Transient | Scoped | Singleton}<IPublisher, DummyPublisher>();
}

